# NAudio BufferedWaveProvider BufferDuration limit causing reading to stop after certain time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, text-to-speech, naudio, naturallyspeaking

I have a text to speech engine that reads exam questions. The reader seems to be working fine, but I have picked up an issue when there is a large text to continuously read.

After 12 Min (every time) the reader just stops reading. I have traced this to have something to do with the Naudio `BufferedWaveProvider`'s `BufferDuration`. Here is my code:

```
Shared waveOut As WaveOut
    Shared waveFormat As WaveFormat
    Shared provider As BufferedWaveProvider

    Private Shared Function InitializeAudio(Freq As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            bNoAudioDected = False
            waveOut = New WaveOut()
            waveFormat = New WaveFormat(Freq, 16, 1)


            provider = New BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat)
            provider.BufferLength = 31457280

           ''this was added for temporary duration fix
             Dim ts = New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
             provider.BufferDuration = ts
           '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


            provider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = True
            Try
                waveOut.Init(provider)
            Catch mmEx As NAudio.MmException
                ErrorMessage("Audio device not detected!" & vbNewLine & "Please connect an audio device to use the Text-To-Speech system!")
                bNoAudioDected = True
                bAudioInitialised = True
                Return False
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteError(ex, "TextToSpeech -> InitializeAudio")
                bNoAudioDected = True
                bAudioInitialised = True
                Return False
            End Try

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub ReleaseAudio()
        Try
            If provider IsNot Nothing Then
                provider.ClearBuffer()
            End If

            If waveOut IsNot Nothing Then
                waveOut.[Stop]()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

I noticed that the default `BufferDuration` is set to : **11:53 min**. I changed this in code to 10 seconds using `TimeSpan`. After 10 seconds the system did exactly the same as the 12 min issue.

I have since changed the duration manualy as per my code above, first to 6 hours (just to over compensate), this cause the system to bomb out instantly. Then to 2 hours which seemed to be working fine, but cause issue with smaller text selections. Then to 30 min, what it is now currently and this seems to be stable but I'm concerned with the reliability since my other two attempts seemed to have caused more issues.

My questions is basically if this is a limitation to NAudio's dll that it can only handle that amount of continuous reading?

Should the BufferDuration be changed as I'm currently doing it or should the default value stay the same?

**EDIT**

Here is the Text-To-Speech wrapper class that I use. Note that this was provided by the Text-To-Speech provider I use.

```
Imports NAudio.Wave
Imports VENET
Imports System.Threading.Thread

Public Class TextToSpeech
#Region "Variables"
#Region "Shared"
    Shared sText As String
    Shared sDir As String()
    Public Shared iSpeechRate As Integer = 100

    Shared hTtsInstance As IntPtr
    Shared hTtsCl As IntPtr
    Public Shared bUploadTypePaper As Boolean = False

#End Region
#Region "Global"
    Dim lstText As List(Of String)
    Dim nErr As NUAN_ERROR
    Dim tts As New VETts
    Dim Lang As VE_LANGUAGE()
    Dim Voice As VE_VOICEINFO()
    Dim thread As Threading.Thread

#End Region
#End Region
#Region "Properties"
    Private _newSpeed As Integer
    Public Property NewSpeed() As Integer
        Get
            Return _newSpeed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _newSpeed = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

    Private SpeechHandler As New VENET.VE_OUTPUTDEVICE(AddressOf StreamSpeech)

    Private Function StreamSpeech(hTtsInst As IntPtr, Msg As VE_MSG, Param As VE_LPARAM, OutData As VE_OUTDATA) As NUAN_ERROR
        Try
            If OutData.pOutPcmBuf IsNot Nothing Then
                provider.AddSamples(OutData.pOutPcmBuf, 0, CInt(OutData.ulPcmBufLen))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("StreamSpeech FAILED: " & nErr)
            MessageBox.Show("StreamSpeech FAILED: " & ex.InnerException.ToString())
        End Try

        Return NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK


    End Function



    Private Sub ExecuteTts()
        Try

            NewSpeed = TtsSpeechSpeed

            nErr = tts.ve_ttsGetLanguageList(hTtsCl, Lang)
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsGetLanguageList FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Lang.Length = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("There are no available languages!")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            nErr = tts.ve_ttsGetVoiceList(hTtsCl, Lang(iLang).szLanguage, 0, Voice)
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsGetVoiceList FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Voice.Length = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("There are no available voices!")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim paramList() As VE_PARAM

            paramList = New VE_PARAM() {New VE_PARAM(VE_PARAMID.VE_PARAM_LANGUAGE, Lang(iLang).szLanguage), New VE_PARAM(VE_PARAMID.VE_PARAM_SPEECHRATE), New VE_PARAM(VE_PARAMID.VE_PARAM_VOICE, Voice(iVoice).szVoiceName)}

            If NewSpeed <> 0 Then
                iSpeechRate = NewSpeed
            ElseIf NewSpeed = 0 Then
                paramList(1).usValue = iSpeechRate
            End If

            paramList(1).usValue = iSpeechRate

            Try
                nErr = tts.ve_ttsSetParamList(hTtsInstance, paramList)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsSetParamList FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim FreqParam As VE_PARAM() = {New VE_PARAM(VE_PARAMID.VE_PARAM_FREQUENCY)}

            nErr = tts.ve_ttsGetParamList(hTtsInstance, FreqParam)
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsGetParamList FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            tts.tts_setOutDevice(SpeechHandler)

            ' Start Streaming Audio
            Try
                waveOut.Play()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


            nErr = tts.ve_ttsProcessText2Speech(hTtsInstance, VE_TEXTFORMAT.VE_NORM_TEXT, sText)

            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK And nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_E_TTS_USERSTOP Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsProcessText2Speech FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("ExecuteTts FAILED: " & nErr)
            MessageBox.Show("ExecuteTts FAILED: " & ex.Message.ToString())
            MessageBox.Show("ExecuteTts FAILED: " & ex.InnerException.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub



    Public Function InitialiseTtsEngine() As Boolean
        Try


            sDir = {sTtsEnginePath}

            nErr = tts.ve_ttsInitialize(sDir, hTtsCl)
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsInitialize FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Function
            End If

            nErr = tts.ve_ttsOpen(hTtsCl, hTtsInstance)
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsOpen FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Function
            End If

            If Not InitializeAudio(22050) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Could not initialize audio with sampling frequency")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub CleanUp()
        If hTtsInstance <> 0 Then
            nErr = tts.ve_ttsStop(hTtsInstance)
            Application.DoEvents()
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsStop FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Sleep(1500)

            nErr = tts.ve_ttsClose(hTtsInstance)
            Application.DoEvents()
            If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsClose FAILED: " & nErr)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Function UnInitialiseTtsEngineForTest() As Boolean

        Try
            If hTtsInstance <> 0 Then

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsStop(hTtsInstance)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsStop FAILED: " & nErr)

                End If

                Sleep(1500)

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsClose(hTtsInstance)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsClose FAILED: " & nErr)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsUnInitialize(hTtsCl)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsUnInitialize FAILED: " & nErr)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                ReleaseAudio()

                GC.Collect()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function UnInitialiseTtsEngineForQTCTest() As Boolean

        Try
            If hTtsInstance <> 0 Then

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsStop(hTtsInstance)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsStop FAILED: " & nErr)

                End If

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsClose(hTtsInstance)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsClose FAILED: " & nErr)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsUnInitialize(hTtsCl)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsUnInitialize FAILED: " & nErr)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                ReleaseAudio()

                GC.Collect()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function UnInitialiseTtsEngine() As Boolean

        Try
            If hTtsInstance <> 0 Then

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsClose(hTtsInstance)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsClose FAILED: " & nErr)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                nErr = tts.ve_ttsUnInitialize(hTtsCl)
                Application.DoEvents()
                If nErr <> NUAN_ERROR.NUAN_OK Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ve_ttsUnInitialize FAILED: " & nErr)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                ReleaseAudio()

                GC.Collect()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Sub PlayTts(ByVal text As String)
        Try

            sText = text

            If thread IsNot Nothing Then
                tts.ve_ttsStop(hTtsInstance)
                ReleaseAudio()
                thread.Join()
                thread = Nothing
            End If
            thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ExecuteTts)
            thread.Start()

        Catch ex As Exception


        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub PauseResumeTts()
        Try
            If waveOut.PlaybackState = PlaybackState.Playing Then
                waveOut.Pause()
            ElseIf waveOut.PlaybackState = PlaybackState.Paused Then
                waveOut.Resume()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteError(ex, "TextToSpeech -> PlayPauseTts")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Shared waveOut As WaveOut
    Shared waveFormat As WaveFormat
    Shared provider As BufferedWaveProvider

    Private Shared Function InitializeAudio(Freq As Integer) As Boolean

        If bUploadTypePaper = True Then


            Try
                bNoAudioDected = False
                waveOut = New WaveOut()
                waveFormat = New WaveFormat(Freq, 16, 1)


                provider = New BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat)
                provider.BufferLength = 31457280
                Dim ts = New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
                provider.BufferDuration = ts
                provider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = True
                Try
                    waveOut.Init(provider)
                Catch mmEx As NAudio.MmException
                    ErrorMessage("Audio device not detected!" & vbNewLine & "Please connect an audio device to use the Text-To-Speech system!")
                    bNoAudioDected = True
                    bAudioInitialised = True
                    Return False
                Catch ex As Exception
                    WriteError(ex, "TextToSpeech -> InitializeAudio")
                    bNoAudioDected = True
                    bAudioInitialised = True
                    Return False
                End Try

                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End If


        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''This was provided
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Try
            bNoAudioDected = False
            waveOut = New WaveOut()
            waveFormat = New WaveFormat(Freq, 16, 1)


            provider = New BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat)
            provider.BufferLength = 31457280
            provider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = True
            Try
                waveOut.Init(provider)
            Catch mmEx As NAudio.MmException
                ErrorMessage("Audio device not detected!" & vbNewLine & "Please connect an audio device to use the Text-To-Speech system!")
                bNoAudioDected = True
                bAudioInitialised = True
                Return False
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteError(ex, "TextToSpeech -> InitializeAudio")
                bNoAudioDected = True
                bAudioInitialised = True
                Return False
            End Try

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub ReleaseAudio()
        Try
            If provider IsNot Nothing Then
                provider.ClearBuffer()
            End If

            If waveOut IsNot Nothing Then
                waveOut.[Stop]()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code I use when I click on the "read text" button:

```
If CStr(currentSelection.type) <> "None" Then
            Dim range As IHTMLTxtRange = TryCast(currentSelection.createRange(), IHTMLTxtRange)
            If IsNothing(range.text) Then
                MessageBox.Show("There is no available text to be read!", "No Text Available", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If range IsNot Nothing Then
                CallTts(range.text)
            End If
        ElseIf currentSelection Is Nothing And String.IsNullOrEmpty(browserContents) Then
            MessageBox.Show("There is no available text to be read!", "No Text Available", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            CallTts(browserContents)
        End If
```

And finally the `CallTts` function code which then goes to the TextToSpeech class provided:

```
Try
  If thread IsNot Nothing Then
      tts.ve_ttsStop(hTtsInstance)
      ReleaseAudio()
      thread.Join()
      thread = Nothing
  End If
  thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ExecuteTts)
  thread.Start()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea behind `BufferedWaveProvider` is that one thread is filling it up while another thread is reading from it. The rate of filling and reading needs to be roughly the same, otherwise the filling thread will overflow the buffer or the reading thread will have dropouts. If you're trying to set the size of the buffer to several hours, it sounds like your use case is not a good fit for `BufferedWaveProvider` at all. How are you adding the audio to `BufferedWaveProvider`?

Comment: Hi Mark, I have edited my question with more info and code if this would help. As you can see with the edit, the Text To Speech wrapper class I am using was provided by the Text To Speech provider. They added the `BufferLength = 31457280`. Without this, the `BufferDuration` is set to about 5 seconds at default. Just as the stream starts, after 5 seconds it stops as with my original example of 12 min and 10 seconds respectively. The only reason for setting the duration is as a temporary fix to have the reader not stop after 12 min. Also they say that since NAudio is 3rd party, they cant help...